# C++ WinAPI error when GetOpenFileName

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012

Good day. I made a class to work OpenFileDialog:

```
#include <Windows.h>

enum DialogResult { OK, Cancel };

class IFileDialog
{
public: 
    TCHAR FileName[MAX_PATH];
    LPTSTR Title;
    virtual DialogResult Show() = 0;
};

class COpenFileDialog  : public IFileDialog
{
public:
    LPTSTR Filter;
    LPTSTR DefExt;
    COpenFileDialog(HWND hWnd);
    DialogResult Show();
private:
    OPENFILENAME m_ofn;
};

COpenFileDialog::COpenFileDialog(HWND hWnd)
{
    //FileName[0] = '\0';

    ZeroMemory(&m_ofn, sizeof(m_ofn));

    m_ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(m_ofn);
    m_ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    m_ofn.lpstrFilter = Filter;
    m_ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    m_ofn.lpstrFile = FileName;
    m_ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
    m_ofn.lpstrDefExt = DefExt;
}

DialogResult COpenFileDialog::Show()
{
    return GetOpenFileName(&m_ofn) ? DialogResult::OK : DialogResult::Cancel;
}
```

Calling:

```
COpenFileDialog hDialog = COpenFileDialog(hMainWindow);
hDialog.Filter = "M&B Scenes\0*.sco\0";
hDialog.DefExt = "sco";
hDialog.Title = "";

if(hDialog.Show() == DialogResult::OK)
{
    //TODO
}
```

But the program crushes on hDialog.Show(), but rather a call GetOpenFileName(&m_ofn):Unhandled exception at 0x000007FDFC5D21A3 (SHCore.dll) in ScoEditor.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000E600000000.

How can I fix it?

Comment: This is not the problem, but do note you're assigning string literals to non-const `char` pointers. Better change the type of `Filter`, `DefExt` and `Title` to `LPCTSTR` to avoid accidentally writing to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor does `m_ofn.lpstrFilter = Filter;`, but `Filter` has not yet been initialized. Later, your code modifies `Filter`, but fails to update the value inside `m_ofn.lpstrFilter`. As a result, you are passing an uninitialized `lpstrFilter` to `GetOpenFileName`.

You would have discovered this if you debugged your code by setting a breakpoint on the call to `GetOpenFileName` and looking at the contents of the `m_ofn` you are passing.